# How to hide cdkMenu without outside click?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I have "add location" button, which opens cdkMenu

```
<button class="btn btn--add" cdkMenuItem [cdkMenuTriggerFor]="locationAdd">
<ng-template #locationAdd>
    <div class="menu-panel" cdkMenu></div>
</ng-template>
</button>
```

Now I want close cdkMenu in my ts file like the right click.
I've tried

```
@ViewChild('locationAdd') locationAdd: CdkContextMenuTrigger;
```

But it doesnt help.